# Open web directory to simple webpage

Tags: javascript, html

This is a fairly simple problem, I'm just not sure exactly how to approach it.

A friend of mine has an open directory on his webserver, and he asked me to make a simple webpage for him which would just display all of the file names, rather than the dates/file sizes/etc. The page would also update when a new file is added into the directory.

So, I guess I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction on this one. My first guess was just to throw a simple HTML/Javascript page together which would extract all of the file names from the directory with Javascript, then display them on the webpage while linking to the file. Or am I going able this all wrong?

Thanks,
aqzman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a client-side language and really has no way of enumerating files and directories on a web server, without the aid of a server-side script anyway.  You need to look into server-side scripting languages such as [Python](http://python.org/), [PHP](http://php.net), and [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) (Windows Server only), to name a few.

These languages are processed on the server and make changes to (or even create from scratch) a page before it is sent to the client/browser.

Comment: Thanks, after talking with my friend he agreed to installed either PHP or ASP.NET onto his server. It would've been painful to do in Javascript. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache's built-in directory listing feature. With javascript this can't really be done (exception: there's a pattern within the filenames that would let you send HEAD requests to see if files exist - see [this site](http://andre-hoenicke.de) where I had to use this technique).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with PHP -

```
$files = scandir($_GET['dir']);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_dir($_GET['dir']))
        echo '<a href="?dir='.$_GET['dir'].'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
    else
        echo '<a href="'$_GET['dir'].'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
}
```